# Creating a probability histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram, probability

I am currently very new to R and have no coding experience. I am trying to make  probability histogram where n=10 with X being a discrete uniform variable on 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, nor a site for getting tutorial recommendations. StackOverflow _is_ a great place for getting help when you're stuck and can't figure out why your code isn't working the way you want. Questions are best-received if you show what you've tried, and clearly explain what isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
hist(sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)
```

So hist() makes a histogram
Sample() let's you input a set of objects to choose from, how many you want and indicate if you are sampling with replacement or not.

In your case, 1:10 is the set of integers from 1 to 10, choosing n=10 of them with replacement (because you don't just want 1:10)